# IdSrv3 authentication without user

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js, identityserver3, openid-connect

I have two applications. First is MVC application, second is node.js application. MVC uses IdentityServer3 for authentication. I want to do screenshoots of MVC pages from node.js. I have phantom.js for this purpose. How to get token in node.js application without user? I want to open phantom.js with that token in header. I think it's possible. Node.js works as service and must make screenshoots every hour:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

client credentials flow is user less and serves your needs.

Comment: Thank you very much. That helped me a lot))